# create a new Object with using previous Variable of constructor

Tags: java, object, constructor

I am creating a new Object of Attendace. The first parameter generates me random animals, that works 
 perfectly, however if i check if the random animal is a cat it still return me a false, also if its a 
 cat, what could be my mistake?

```
 public enum Animal{
            DOG,
            CAT,
            HORSE
            }

            public class Attendace {
                private Animal animal;
                private boolean present;
                private static int count;

                public Attendace (Animal animal, boolean present) {
                    this.animal = animal;
                    this.present= present;
                }

                public Attendace() {}

                public static boolean presence{
                 Attendace a = new Attendace();
                 if(a.animal == Animal.CAT && count == 0){
                  ++count;
                  return true;
                 }
                 return false
                }     
            }


            new Attendace(Animal.randomEnum(), Attendace.presence());

);
```

Comment: What do you think `Attendace a = new Attendace();` does?

Comment: You are using the default constructor, you should use this version `public Attendace (Animal animal, boolean present)` and pass Animal cat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `presence` you are creating a new instance of `Attendance` without giving it an `Animal`, meaning `animal` stays `null`.

Instead, change `presence` to this:

```
public boolean presence() {
    int count = 0;
    if (animal == Animal.CAT && count == 0) {
        ++count;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

...remove `boolean presence` from the constructor and instead call the function.

```
public Attendace (Animal animal) {
    this.animal = animal;
    this.present = presence();
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, but the methode have to be static. so i cannot use animal without an object

Comment: Then use smithnblack solution, seems like it would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

For the `instance a` you are using the `constructor` without input parameters. Thats why your `private Animal` is `null`.

To fix this, pass your animal to your `a object constructor` like you did in the last line:

```
public static boolean presence{
             Attendace a = new Attendace(Animal.randomEnum(), Attendace.presence());
             if(a.animal == Animal.CAT && count == 0){
              ++count;
              return true;
             }
             return false
            }
```

Comment: that wouldn't work, because i don't  want to generate a random animal in the presence methode for a second time

Comment: @heapoverflow Then your logic is broken. Either make the method not static and use the animal of the instance, or generate a new one in `presence` or outside `presence` and pass it as an argument.